# Delete selected images from a row containing multiple cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView containing list of images, each row contains 4 `UITableViewCell`,
the user can select multiple images (selection is by hiding and showing an overlay image on the cell) 
what i want to do is when user click delete button is to remove the selected image from my table.

Here is some of the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
ThumbnailImageCell *cell = (ThumbnailImageCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if (cell == nil)
{               
    cell = [[[ThumbnailImageCell alloc] initWithManagedImages:[self imagesForIndexPath:indexPath] reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}   
else
{       
    [cell setImages:[self imagesForIndexPath:indexPath]];
}

return cell;}



-(NSArray*)imagesForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)_indexPath {

int index = (_indexPath.row*4);
int maxIndex = (_indexPath.row*4+3);

if(maxIndex < [self.imagesArray count]) {

    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index],
            [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index+1],
            [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index+2],
            [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index+3],
            nil];
}

else if(maxIndex-1 < [self.imagesArray count]) {

    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index],
            [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index+1],
            [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index+2],
            nil];
}

else if(maxIndex-2 < [self.imagesArray count]) {

    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index],
            [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index+1],
            nil];
}

else if(maxIndex-3 < [self.imagesArray count]) {

    return [NSArray arrayWithObject:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index]];
}

return nil;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return ceil([self.imagesArray count] / 4.0);
}
```

What I tried to do is the following but without any success till now

```
-(void)finishDeleting{
int countOfDeletedThread;
[self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

NSMutableIndexSet *mutableIndexSet = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *indexToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSIndexPath *indexPath ;

for(ThumbnailImage *thumbnailImage in self.imagesArray)
{
    if([thumbnailImage selected])
    {
       countOfDeletedThread = countOfDeletedThread+1;
       indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:countOfDeletedThread inSection:0];

        [indexToDelete addObject:indexPath];
        [mutableIndexSet addIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
}
[self.imagesArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:mutableIndexSet];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[indexToDelete release];
[mutableIndexSet release];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[CATransaction flush];}
```

Any help please? I am stuck for 2 days and don't know what to do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you have 4 `UIImageView`s per table row, not
4 `UITableViewCell`s. That means if you delete a subset of the images, the remaining
images will "reflow" across all rows. Therefore it does not make sense to use 
`beginUpdates/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths/endUpdates`. You probably should just

- remove the selected images from the data source array `self.imagesArray`,
- call `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

Removing the selected images from the array can be slightly simplified to

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [self.imagesArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(ThumbnailImage *thumbnailImage, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [thumbnailImage selected];
}];
[self.imagesArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
```

Note that [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) (available since iOS 6) might be better suited to display
multiple images per row.

Comment: it worked great..
Thank you so much
you saved my day :)

I dont have enough reputation to vote your answer up since it is my first post .. but you earned my respect:) +1